# Jquery of datatables unable to retrieve row

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Here is my code i am using the Datatable ajax function and decided to use this way to retrieve the email which is data[2], it alert click and undefined

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        alert('clicked');
        var data = table.row( this ).data(); 
        //table.fnGetData(this);
        //table.row( this ).data()      
        var email = "mailto:"+(data[2]);
       // console.log(newPage);
        alert(email);
        window.location.href = email;
    });
```

here is my datatables ajax

```
    var table=$('#example').DataTable({


        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : false,

        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "CompareSchool?year="+year,
            "type" : "get",
        },
        "columns" : 
            [

                {
                    "data" : "name"
                }, 
                {
                    "data" : "number"
                },
                {
                    "data" : "email"
                }, 
                {
                    "data" : "year"
                } 
            ]
    }

    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using following option for email column so you do not need to call email click event using java script :

```
{
    "data" : "email",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        return ( type === 'display' ) ? '<a href="mailto:'+data+'" title="'+data+'">'+data+'</a>' : data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but could you tell me how does the function works i tried mRender before and it gave me an error like the parameter it took was undefined

Sorry i cannot mark this as answer though, kinda need know why not working hahaha :) thanks anyway

Comment: mRender will work if you have define column with aoColumnDefs option because in data table some options are for its jQuery object instance and some for API instance.

Comment: i did use "aoColumnDefs" here is a part of the code

 "aoColumnDefs": [  {
          "aTargets": [ 2 ],                                                 
          "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
           
           return '<a href="/mailto/' + full[2] + '">' + "data" + '</a>';
          }
         }

Comment: i just realize comments cannot do indentation